# How to resolve java.lang.IllegalStateException: The maximum number of cell styles was exceeded. You can define up to 4000 styles in a .xls workbook

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have too much data in table whlie genrating the .xls file, I am getting cell type exception, the code I am using

```
int i = 0;
    HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet(name);
    sheet.setDefaultColumnWidth(19);
    //
    setWorkbookFooterHSSF(sheet);
    HSSFRow headingsRow = workBook.getSheet(name).createRow((short) 0);
    HSSFFont headingFont = workBook.createFont();
    headingFont.setBold(true);
    HSSFCellStyle headingStyle = workBook.createCellStyle();        
    headingStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    headingStyle.setFont(headingFont);
    headingStyle.setWrapText(true);
    //HSSFCell headingA = headingsRow.createCell(i);
    if (iptExcelHeader != null && iptExcelHeader.size() != 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < iptExcelHeader.size(); i++) {
            HSSFCell headingA = headingsRow.createCell((short) i);
            String value = iptExcelHeader.get(i) != null ? iptExcelHeader.get(i).toString() : "";
            headingA.setCellValue(value);
            headingA.setCellStyle(headingStyle);

        }
    }
    return workBook;

}
```

The code for addcontent

```
 public static HSSFWorkbook addContentMaintenanceHSSF(HSSFWorkbook workBook,
        ArrayList iptExcelContent, int rowNum, String name) {

    HSSFRow row = workBook.getSheet(name).createRow((short) rowNum);
    LOG.debug("inside excel content method");
    // if(iptExcelContent!=null && iptExcelContent.size()!=0){
    if(iptExcelContent!=null && !(iptExcelContent.isEmpty())){ //sonar fix
        CellStyle cellPlanIdStyle = workBook.createCellStyle();
        cellPlanIdStyle.setDataFormat((short) 7);
        for (int i = 0; i < iptExcelContent.size(); i++) {
            HSSFCell cellPlanId = row.createCell((short) i);
            cellPlanId.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
            if (iptExcelContent.get(i) != null) {
                String contentValue = ((String) iptExcelContent.get(i));

                cellPlanId.setCellValue(contentValue);

            }
            else
            {
                cellPlanId.setCellValue("");
            }
        }
    }
    return workBook;
}
```

Whats wrong with my code, I am using apche poi 3.17.jar and wildfly server. if I deploy same code on Jboss 4.2 then I am not getting Cellstyle exception for same .xls file
anyone can help me resolve this, give your valuable comment

Comment: Create the cell styles once and re-use, don't create one cell style per cell!

Comment: Thanks for replying, but can you explain in details like how I can do that?

Comment: addContentMaintenanceHSSF adds one row but you create a brand new style instance -- CellStyle cellPlanIdStyle = workBook.createCellStyle() -- you can create that cell style instance once when you create the HSSFWorkbook and pass the cellPlanIdStyle into the addContentMaintenanceHSSF methods as a parameter

Comment: Ok. I will try- thanks you so much for replying